# Codeigniter LIKE search always returns the whole table

Tags: search, codeigniter

When I the search function, no matter what I get back all the entries in the searched DB table.

This is the controller:

```
function search()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'company field', 'required');

    $search_text = $this->input->post('name');
    $is_ajax = $this->input->post('ajax');

    $data['found_companies'] = $this->Company->get_companies_by_name($search_text);
$data['page_title'] = 'Search';

$this->load->view('head', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/search', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

this is the model function `get_companies_by_name` that does the search:

```
function get_companies_by_name($name) {

    $this->db->select('id,name,logo,phone,email,adress,url,contact,contact_phone,biz_id,join_date,user,password');
    $this->db->like('name', $name, 'after');

$returned = $this->db->get('companies');
return $returned;
}
```

and this is the view part that displays the search:

```
    <?php

validation_errors();

    echo form_open("pages/search",$attributes);
        echo form_input('company','');
        echo form_submit('submit','חפש');
        echo form_close();


        foreach ($found_companies->result() as $company) { ?>

                    <?= img("uploads/thumbs/" . $company->logo);?>
                    <?= $company->id; ?>
                    <?= anchor ("admin/home/$company->id", "$company->name</br>"); ?>
                    <?= $company->phone;?>
                    <?= $company->email;?>
                    <?= $company->adress;?>
                    <?= $company->url;?>
                    <?= $company->contact;?>
                    <?= $company->contact_phone;?>
                    <?= $company->biz_id;?>
                    <?= $company->join_date;?>
                    <?= $company->user;?>
                    <?= $company->password;?>
                    <?= anchor ("bizadmin/del/$company->id", "מחק עסק</br>")." ".anchor ("admin/edit/$company->id", "ערוך עסק</br>")." ".anchor ("admin/editcamp/$campaign_id->id", "ערוך קמפיין</br>"); ?>
                </br>

    <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
    $search_text = $this->input->post('name');
```

with

```
    $search_text = $this->input->post('company');
```

in function search()

Comment: Yup. Because of the mis-match of your input field and your POST variable on the receiving end, your search text is always empty, so your query is always "LIKE '%'", which matches all.